# Cannot align text in image slider using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, slider

I'm learning html and css so i'm not so good in this. I making the image slider like this -https://websites.co.in/

which includes image and text in one container.
I'm able to rotate image and text properly, but having problem in aligning text.
This is what i made- https://ajaygohel.000webhostapp.com

I want exactly same text alignment as 1st link.

**Html code for slider**

```
<div id="container">
    <span class="right"><p>1</p></span>
    <img class="slides" src="images/slider1.jpg">
    <span class="right"><p>2</p></span>
    <img class="slides" src="images/slider2.jpg">
    <span class="right"><p>3</p></span>
    <img class="slides" src="images/slider3.jpg">
    <span class="right"><p>4</p></span>
    <img class="slides" src="images/slider4.jpg">
    <span class="right"><p>5</p></span>
    <img class="slides" src="images/slider5.jpg">
    <button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(-1)" id="btnprev">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(1)" id="btnnext">&#10095;</button>   
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
#container{
width: 90%;
height: 450px;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
#container img{
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
float: right;
}
#container .btn{
position: absolute;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border: none;
border-radius: 25px;
top: 200px;
background: black;
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
}
#container #btnprev:hover{
box-shadow: 10px 0 20px 0 black;
}
#container #btnnext{
position: relative;
float: right;
}
#container #btnnext:hover{
box-shadow: -10px 0 20px 0 black;
}
.right{
float: right;
position: relative; 
}
.right p{
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are centering the paragraph itself when its container doesn't fill half the width of the slider. What you need to do is expand the right container (.right) to the correct width and center all of its contents:

```
.right {
    float: right;
    position: relative; 
    width: 50%; /* MAKE THE CONTAINER THE RIGHT SIZE */
    text-align: center; /* CENTER ALL TEXT INSIDE THIS */
}

.right p {
    /* text-align: center; <= THIS ISN'T NEEDED */
}
```

Your next button is also placed with a float instead of making use of the absolute positioning that is already applied to its `.btn` class. To fix this after changing the text, remove the float and relative positioning overrides, and set `right: 0` (to move it zero pixels from the right side of the slider):

```
#container #btnnext {
    right: 0; /* <= ADD THIS (or set in pixels to add distance from edge) */
    /* position: absolute; <= REMOVE THIS */
    /* float: right; <= REMOVE THIS */
}
```

Comment: The button wasn't positioned in the same way as the prev one. I've updated the answer with a fix for that.

Comment: Ty so much. its perfect now

Answer (score 0):

You just needs to add width and align property into the ".right" class like

```
.right {
width : calc(100% / 2);
text-align : center;
}
```